# how to use one shared log4j configure file in multiple java projects

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I used one log4j2.xml file configuration in a Java project named "common" 
now I want to use this configuration file directly (without copy) in the other two Java projects named "a" and "b".

how can I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Package the log4j2.xml configuration file in a jar file library and use that library in both projects.